# module.js: 549 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module 'D:\Day'

Tags: protractor

While running protractor test in eclipse, I am getting this error:

[image]

but while running from command prompt it is working..

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in the folder name `Day User`, and try again.

Comment: Yup, realised later on that day itself and it worked. Thanks anyway for taking a look